# How to use meta name in bundle.js?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bundle

How do I use meta name in the `bundle.js`?

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<meta content="" name="keywords">
<meta content="" name="description">
```